# How to add items to NSToolBar in Xcode 6 Mavericks(Using storyboards)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, storyboard, xcode6, nstoolbar

So I am using the new Xcode 6 on mavericks. I am also using storyboards in the project. I currently have a NSToolBar with the default items that it comes with, but I can't add any items to it, I try to double click it, double click the items in NSToolBar but I can't get the panel where you are supposed to drag them into to show up like apple's website tutorial says. I remember having been able to add items in Xcode 5 before. Is there another way in Xcode 6 or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixes with the Xcode 6.1 GM version. Adding items to the NSToolBar is now possible by double clicking it in the IB.